# re-order alphabet sorting in Perl

Tags: perl, sorting, alphabetical

I am trying to fix sorting in Armenian alphabet, because all standard Unix tools and programming languages sort letters and words as a result for only 1 of the 2 major dialects (Western).

Translating this into technical problem is to re-order one of the chars "**ւ**", to put it in different place among letters, let's say to make it the last character so that words are ordered correctly for the order dialect (Eastern). Linguistically speaking in Eastern dialect this "**ւ**" symbol is not written "standalone" but is a part of letter that's written with 2 chars "*ու*". Current sorting puts letter "*ու*" behind "ոք" or "ոփ" 2-letter constructs.

Basically, it should be totally similar if you wanted to make e. g. letter "v" be on place of letter "z" in Latin alphabet.

I am trying to use something like

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my (@sortd, @unsortd, $char_u, $char_x);
#@unsortd = qw(աբասի ապուշ ապրուստ թուր թովիչ թոշակ թոք);
@unsortd = qw(ու ոց ոք ոփ);

@sortd = sort {
  $char_u = "ւ";
  $char_x = split(//, @unsortd);
  if ($char_u gt $char_x) {
    1;
  } else {
    return $a cmp $b;
  } 
} @unsortd;

print "@sortd\n";
```

but that does not scale for whole words, just 2 letter forms are fixed.

UPDATE: I was able to solve this using *tr* function to map letters to numbers as shown in [Perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=897223)

Comment: You should never sort text using code point comparisons; it is just never going to be right. That’s why `Unicode::Collate` and `Unicode::Collate`  exist.

Answer (score 12):

You should have a look at the [Unicode::Collate::Locale](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Unicode%3a%3aCollate%3a%3aLocale) module if you haven't done so already.

```
use Unicode::Collate::Locale;

my $collator = Unicode::Collate::Locale->new(locale => "hy");
@sortd = $collator->sort(@unsortd);
print join("\n", @sortd, '');
```

This prints:

```
ու
ոց
ոք
ոփ
```

(I'm not sure this is the output you're expecting, but that module and `Unicode::Collate` has quite a lot of information, it might be easier to create a custom collation for your needs based on that rather than rolling your own.)

Comment: I tried with both Unicode:Collate and use:locale, but it's just the same. I would need similar code that puts some Latin letter on place of "z" in word ordering.

Comment: @user278192 You do not want `use locale` — virtually ever!! You want `Unicode::Collate::Locale`, and you specify the Armenian locale in the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

For standard alphabets `Unicode::Collate::Locale` as suggested by @mat should be the first choice.

On the other hand, if you have very specific needs `index' can be used as follows. To sort single characters (note that missing characters would be first):

```
my $alphabet_A = "acb";
sub by_A {index($alphabet_A,$a) <=> index($alphabet_A,$b)};

...

my @sorted = sort by_A @unsorted;
```

For words, one can include a loop in the definition of by_A. For the following to work define the function min() and fine-tune the case of words of different lengths:

```
sub by_A {
    $flag=0;
    foreach my $i (0..min(length($a),length($b))-1) { 
        return ($flag) if ($flag);
        $flag = ($flag or 
                 index($alphabet_A,substr($a,$i,1)) <=> index($alphabet_A,substr($b,$i,1)));
    }
    return $flag;
}
```